# String.nextLine() Java - Crashing

Tags: java, string, exception, nosuchelementexception

I'm still having an issue with the line String parts = input.nextLine();. It keeps crashing and if i remove "Line", it is fine but i want to read the whole String including spaces and store it.  Assuming that I have declared all the variables and array previously.

```
System.out.print("Enter registration number of vehicle: ");
String inputREGO = input.nextLine();
System.out.print(inputREGO);
boolean flag = false;
for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    if(inputREGO.equalsIgnoreCase(services[i].getregoNUMBER())){
        System.out.print("Enter Part Description: ");

        String parts = input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter Part Cost: ");

        Double cost = input.nextDouble();
        services[i].addPARTDETAILS(parts, cost);
        flag = true;
    }
}

if(!flag)
    System.out.println("No registration number were found in the system.");

public boolean addPARTDETAILS(String partDESCRIPTION, double partCOST){
    if(partDESCRIPTION.isEmpty() || partCOST <= 0){
        System.out.println("Invalid input, please try again!");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();
        strBuf.append("    ").append(partDESCRIPTION).append(" ($").append(partCOST).append(")");
        partLIST += strBuf;
        System.out.printf("\n%10s", partLIST);
        System.out.println("\n Parts recorded successfully for vehicle " + getregoNUMBER());
        totalPART+=partCOST;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is input declared as?

Comment: what type has "input" ?

Comment: Please post a stack trace showing what exception is being raised and where. I also suggest you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and these [hints](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Comment: "It keeps crashing" isn't a good description of what's going wrong. It's also very unclear why your variables have halfSHOUTY names.

Comment: input is declared as Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: As I have said before, it does crash, it produces an error message and ignoring it is not very useful as the error is trying to tell you something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [nextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29):

> Throws:
>
> NoSuchElementException - **if no line was found**
>
> IllegalStateException - **if this scanner is closed**

Make sure the scanner is *not closed* before you reach the line that causes the problem.. also make sure that.. *there is a line*.

I don't see any other problem that could cause your program to *"crash"* (You'll help us to help you if you better define what *"crash"* is)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) :

```
BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String text = bufferRead.readLine();
```

or the [scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
   Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
   String text = scanIn.nextLine();
```

both should work without any problems.